# 'Types' node not being listed in the metadata browser in the Connections navigator in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am connected to an Autonomous DB in Oracle Cloud. I created a `TYPE` database object in my schema. When I try to view the details of the `TYPE`, the metadata browser does not even list "`Types`" as a node in the tree structure.

The owner of the type is the schema that I am logged into. I accessed the Object Browser via SQL Workshop in Oracle APEX and I can see that the type that I have created is displayed there.

Is there any setting that I can modify within SQLDeveloper so that it will show me the `Types` node in the navigator?

sqldeveloper version: Version 19.2.1.247
Build: 247.2212
I am using this on MacOS

[image: no types shown in the metadata browser]

Comment: Not related to programming.

Comment: You miss whole lot of things (indexes, types, materialized views, ...). Did you try to press the "Refresh" button (placed in the toolbar right above what is displayed on the screenshot)?

Comment: @Littlefoot - yup, that's right, more nodes are missing. Based on thatjeffsmith's response below, it looks like it was done for a reason and would be potentially made available in future releases.

Comment: @digvijay this is a programming IDE and TYPES are a programming object...so very related to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autonomous team asked us (SQLDev) to hide a bunch of stuff...like indexes, materialized views, etc.

They weren't supported in the first iteration of the service...but now they are.

In a future release (20.2, maybe) these objects will all be displayed again, whether you can create them or not.

Comment: OK, but **why**? I mean, SQL Developer can do zillion of things and has many options (many?) users won't use (such as Data Miner or OLAP or Unit Test). But - most developers do use indexes, create types or materialized views. I just don't understand why would anyone want to "hide" them from the Object viewer.

Comment: There weren't going to be indexes. And other things.. @littlefoot That changed, obviously

Comment: Thank you for replying Jeff. Though, I don't understand what you are saying. Where is "there"? In SQL Developer? Or in "databases" (Oracle, as we're at it)? Maybe term "the Autonomous team" means something important which would make me understand. But - currently, I do not. Oh well, never mind, my (MS Windows) SQL Developer has 19.x has all of these so I'm OK with it. Maybe it is MAC version? Kind of being confused.

Comment: The Autonomous Data Warehouse Cloud Service @littlefoot